# a combinatorial problem due to Kleitman

Tags: combinatorics

imagine a set $X$ with $n$ elements and $‎‎‎‎‎\mathcal{C}‎‎$ the set of all colorings of $X$ with two colors ,it means the set of 2^n mappings such $‎‎‎‎\chi : X ‎\rightarrow ‎\{-1,1\}$.

i define a meter on $‎‎‎‎‎\mathcal{C}‎‎$ as follows:

‎$d(\chi,‎\chi‎')=|\{a:\chi(a)\neq ‎\chi‎'(a)\}|‎$

i've read that Kleitman has proved that if $‎‎‎‎\mathcal{‎D‎‎}‎\subseteq ‎‎\mathcal{C}‎$ ‏and for ‎$‎‎‎r\le ‎\frac{n}{2}‎$‎‎,

‎$|‎\mathcal{D}‎‎|\ge \Sigma‎‎_{i\le r}{{n}\choose{i}}
$
then the diameter of $‎‎‎‎‎\mathcal{D}‎‎$ is at least $2r$.

i am so curios to know the proof.

may anyone help me please?

thanks.

Comment: Kleitman’s 1966 paper is freely available [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980066800273).